# We’ve read or we read?

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-simple

> Books we pretend we ***have read***.

What if instead of ***have read***, I simply wrote we ***read*** ?

Would the meaning of the sentence change?

Answer (score 3):

There’s a slight difference. “We read” implies a completed action, whereas “we have read” implies an action that may continue. Which is best depends on which you mean.

That said, we generally prefer to stick with the simple past for simplicity because such slight differences often don’t matter.  Don’t use a more complicated tense when a simple one suffices.

There’s a glitch with this specific verb in that “read” is spelled the same in simple present and simple past, though it’s pronounced differently. Without other context to clarify which is meant, I might prefer “have read” in writing to show the past even though I’d use “read” in speech.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is it because of the glitch with the word “read” that you would prefer to use “have read” in writing?